# Java алгоритм поиска подстроки

Tags: java, алгоритм

Как можно модифицировать данный алгоритм, чтобы после определения индекса первого вхождения подстроки в строку, он продолжить искать такие же подстроки в строке до ее окончания, а не выходил после первого нахождения.

```
public int substring(String file, String value) {

    int fileLength = file.length();
    int valueLength = value.length();
    if (valueLength > fileLength) {
        return -1;
    }
    HashMap<Character, Integer> cascade = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        cascade.put((char) i, valueLength);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < valueLength - 1; i++) {
        cascade.put(value.charAt(i), valueLength - i - 1);
    }
    int i = valueLength - 1;
    int j = i;
    int k = i;
    while (j >= 0 && i <= fileLength - 1) {
        j = valueLength - 1;
        k = i;
        while (j >= 0 && file.charAt(k) == value.charAt(j)) {
            k--;
            j--;
        }
        i += cascade.get(file.charAt(i));
    }
    if (k >= fileLength - valueLength) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return k + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно воспользоваться методом [`String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-). В начале поиска указать `0` для `fromIndex`, а затем передвинуться на найденный индекс + длинна строки. Есть аналогичный метод для поиска символов.

Answer (score 11):

Если решение данной задачи преследует не учебную или академическую, а практическую цель, можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями.

Ниже пример, который находит в строке все подстроки состоящие из буквы "А" и выводит позицию с которой начинается каждая из них.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
. . .
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("А+");
String s = "АААБББГГГААРРПТВВАААА0";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println("Позиция: " + matcher.start());  
}
```